# Is the Lebesgue Integral of a series finite?

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let, $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space and
$$F(x) = \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}e^{f_k(x)}.$$

If we have that,
$$\int_{X}F(x) ~d\mu < \infty.$$
We then have that,
$F$ is finite almost everywhere on $X$. Let,
$$Z = \{ x \in X: \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}f_k(x) = -\infty\}.$$
Let,
$$ V = \{ x \in X: F(X) = \infty \}.$$

I know that $\mu(V) = 0$ and $Z \subseteq V$; however, is this enough to conclude that $\mu(Z) =0$? since we don't know that $(X, \mathcal{M},\mu)$ is a complete measure space.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you show that $Z\subseteq V$?

Comment: Even if it isn't complete, if $A, B$ are measurable with $\mu(B) = 0$ and $A\subseteq B$ then $\mu(A) = 0$. Completeness only tells you that you don't have to assume that $A$ is measurable.

Comment: @jakobian How do we know that $Z$ is measurable?  I know that $Z \subset V$ because in order for $F(x)$ to be finite it must be that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} e^{fk(x)} = 1$.

Comment: That would be a necessary condition if $F(x) = \prod_{k=1}^\infty e^{f_k(x)}$ but there's a sum there.

Comment: @Jakobian Don't you have $F(x) < \infty \implies \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} e^{f_k(x)} = 0 \implies \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} f_k(x)= 1 $?

Comment: No, $F(x)<\infty \implies \lim_{k\to\infty} f_k(x) = -\infty$

Comment: @Jakobian I don't quite see how you got that, could you please explain some more. Thanks. I think I will solve my problem if I make this confusion clear.

Nvm I see now. thanks.

Comment: @Jakobian, thanks i understand where I messed up now.

Comment: If $x\in \{F<\infty\}$, then $\sum_k e^{f_k(x)}<\infty$ and so $\lim_ke^{f_k(x)}=0$, This means that $\lim_kf_k(x)=-\infty$. In other words, $\{F<\infty\}\subset\{\lim_kf=0\}$